# How Can I get timezone Abbreviation from a timestamp using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want the output to be 
`Time:  Fri Feb 28 12:08:41 EST 2020`

But EST comes as `-0500`

```js
const timestamp = 1582909721636;

const toPrintTimeFormat = (input) => {
  return moment(input).format('ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY');
}

console.log('Time: ', toPrintTimeFormat(timestamp));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use https://momentjs.com/timezone/ for that. See https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162.

```js
const timestamp = 1582909721636;

const toPrintTimeFormat = (input) => {
  return moment(input).tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss z YYYY');
}

console.log('Time: ', toPrintTimeFormat(timestamp));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```